# Import all mixins and vars into .vue files

Tags: webpack, vue.js, global, mixins, nuxt.js

I tried a lot, but I don't know how to make my sass vars, functions and mixins available in my vue files with nuxt.js.

This is my folder structure

```
--pages
    index.vue
--layouts
  header.vue
--styles
  --scss
    --helpers
      _breakpoints.scss
      _colors.scss
      _main.scss
    --vars
      _breakpoints.scss
      _colors.scss
      _main.scss
    main.scss
```

Inside my `styles/scss/` everything works fine. I can import any scss file with no problems, but when I want to get access from a vue file inside my layouts folder, I only get the error:

> File to import not found or unreadable:  ~styles/main.scss.

This is my header.vue file

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "~styles/main.scss";

    .logo{
        width: 120px;
        height: auto;

        @include respond-at("medium"){
            width: 170px;
        };

        @include respond-at("large"){
          width: 220px;
        };
    }
</style>
<template>
    <header>
        <img src="/logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
    </header>
</template>
<script>
...
```

And this is my nuxt.config.js file

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    ...
    css: [
        '~/styles/vendors/sanitize.css',
        '~/styles/scss/main.scss'
    ],

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'styles': path.resolve(__dirname, '~/styles/scss/')
        }
    },
    ...
```

### update:

Ok if i only write

```
@import "styles/scss/main.scss";
```

than it works, but i have to repeat this in every .vue file, where i need the mixins...

But i think that's ok. Then i see at the beginning that there are dependencies to mixins

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to replace `@import "~styles/main.scss";` on `@import "~/styles/main.scss";` ?

Comment: same result 'File to import not found or unreadable: ~/styles/main.scss.'